# Rails3 and Devise working with Iphone/Android/Wp7 applications

Tags: iphone, android, ruby-on-rails-3, windows-phone-7, devise

I searched arround for solutions and didn't find anything of really pertinent on the subject.

This is why, I ask you guys your help :-)

Assuming I have an application running with Rails 3 using Devise to authenticate the users.

I need to create mobile applications for Iphone/Android and WP7.

The mobiles applications should communicate/login/create/list, do whatever the website can do.

The mobile Applications could commuicate by parsing the XML .... but maybe there are already lib/frameworks or something more sexy ?

What would be the best way to communicate between my mobile applications and my Rails website ?

Comment: What is your question?  How to convert your rails site into a phone app?

Comment: What would be the best way to communicate between my mobile applications and my Rails website ?

Comment: Do you mean a Browser? Do you speak of a mobile version of your site or some API offered?

Comment: I speak of a native application using an APi(json or XML or other) to interract with my webservice.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the xml or json output to share data back and forth; For authentication you can set (in initializers/devise.rb)

```
config.http_authenticatable = true
```

That enables you to send basic HTTP Auth headers with every request which devise will handle for you.

--

For creating a webapplication that is also possible to view in a mobile version for the website i'd recommend to check out this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like, if the mobile app is just an interface to the web app, that you would likely be best served by creating a mobile HTML5 "style" within your web app, that gets served automatically when a mobile phone accesses your website.  All of your code can be in Rails, which it sounds like you're already familiar with, and you've also got the advantage of keeping your codebase all together in one place - if you want to add functionality later, you just update your web app, and don't worry about updating 2 different mobile phone apps as well.